# Create a simple bash script 10 random numbers between 1000 and 9999?

Tags: linux

Here is my code to generate a random number

```
#!/bin/bash

clear #Clears the screen to make it easier to read the output
echo -n “Creating a new random four digit PIN for access to the site: “
echo $((RANDOM%8999+1000))
```

How do I get this to print out 10 random numbers?

Comment: Please, can you edit your question ? We won't make any effort to help you if you don't make any effort in your question.

Comment: write a loop....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a loop. Here is the code  that uses a `for` loop but you can use `while` loop as well

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
echo -n “Creating a new random four digit PIN for access to the site: “ 
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    echo $((RANDOM%8999+1000));
done;
```